# Python requests.get(url) returning empty but can't figure out why

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

### UPDATE:

I think I figured out the issue.  I'm using the `requests_cache` module and I likely am continuing to request the URL that returned empty many tests ago from the cache.  In other words, the cache is holding onto a "bug" and I keep silently using that cache request.

---

I am trying to run the following code and it's tripping up because the `requests.get(url)` portion is coming back empty.  I'm looping through a bunch of URLs and the others work fine.  There is something about this one that continues behave this way.

```
urls = ['http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/brogdma01.html',
  'http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/brokaga01.html',
  'http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/brookpr01.html',
  'http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/brookcl01.html',
  'http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/brookaa01.html',
  'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/cookqu01.html']

for url in urls:
  page_source = requests.get(url).text
```

The problem URL is this one: `https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/cookqu01.html`

Anyone know why this one would behave differently?

Comment: Can you check the status_code. Example: requests.get(url).status_code. If it is not 200 then there is some problem with the access or the link. Here is the status code documentation to understand the code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: I tried with the problem URL that you've provided above and for me I am able to get the text. Could you please provide more info.

Comment: Maybe the site rate limits your request. Why don't you tryagain with a time.sleep(2) after each request.

Comment: @lllrnr101 it does rate limit and I've tried with different different sleep intervals and also different orders.  It always errors on that specific URL.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i saw is that your not working url is the only one with "https" instead of "http".

But i think its the same site so this could be your problem.